# Firefox Developer Edition - WebIDE - operation failed, ios proxy not yet supported on winnt

Tags: firefox

Downloaded/installed Firefox Developer Edition, first thing I tried was the WebIDE feature, tried loading "Safari on iOS" and got an error???

Now, I'm on Windows 7, but all the documentation says that this edition lets you use this IDE feature to see what sites look like in other environments. Are they wrong? Is the feature busted? Is there something additional I need to install?

Not great when you download software to try out a feature and the very first thing you try errors.

Comment: OK thanks isim! Unfortunately this was the only feature I was looking forward to. (uninstalls Firefox Developer Edition). Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives you a hint right there. The "Safari on iOS setup" is supported on Linux and Macs only. To quote the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_Tools_Adapter) heading:

> **Safari on iOS setup (Linux and Mac only)**
>
> etc...